# The $n^{th}$ root of the geometric mean of binomial coefficients.

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients

$\{{C_k^n}\}_{k=0}^n$ are binomial coefficients. $G_n$ is their geometrical mean.

Prove 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{G_n}^{1/n}=\sqrt{e}$$

Comment: Unlikely: except for the two extremes they are all at least $n$, and usually quite a bit bigger. Also please show more context (where does this problem come from), and what you've found yourself so far.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sqrt[10]{\prod_{k=0}^{10} \binom{10}{k}}\approx 44.7778$. See [here](http://tinyurl.com/87ujf8j).

Comment: If you want to do without Stirling's approximation, check Q6 in math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/putnam/problems/mock11sol.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$G_n$ is the geometric mean of $n+1$ numbers:
$$
G_n=\left[\prod_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\right]^{\frac1{n+1}}
$$
or with $\log$ representing the natural logarithm (to the base $e$),
$$
\log G_n
= \frac1{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \log {n\choose k}
= \log n! - \frac2{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n \log k!
\,.
$$
Stirling's approximation is
$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$
or
$$
\log n!
 \approx
 \frac12\log{(2\pi n)}+n\log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)
 = \left(n+\frac12\right)\log n+\frac12\log 2\pi-n
$$
so
$$
\eqalign{
\log \left(G_n\right)^\frac1n
&
= \frac1n \log G_n
= \frac1n \log n! - \frac2{n(n+1)} \log \prod_{k=0}^n k!
\\
&
= \frac1n \log n! - \frac2{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=0}^n \log k!
\\
&
\approx \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \log n
- \frac2{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(k+\frac12\right)\log k
- \frac1{2n}\log 2\pi
\\
&
\approx \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \log n
- \frac2{n(n+1)}
  \left[
  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log n - 
  \frac{n(n+2)}{4}
  \right]
- \frac1{2n}\log 2\pi
\\
&
= \frac{\log n-\log 2\pi}{2n}
+ \frac{n+2}{2(n+1)}
\\
&
\rightarrow \frac12
\,,
}
$$
where the sum of logarithms was approximated
using the definite integrals
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \approx
\int_1^n \log x\,dx =
\Big[x\log x-x\Big]_1^n \approx
\Big[x\log x-x\Big]_0^n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k \log k \approx
\int_0^n x\log x\,dx=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\log x - \frac{x^2}{4}\right]_0^n
$$
(using integration by parts as shown in a comment), so that
$$
\eqalign{
\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k+\frac12\right)\log k
&=
\sum_{k=1}^n k \log k + \frac12
\sum_{k=1}^n   \log k
\\
&\approx
\left( \frac{n^2}{2}\log n - \frac{n^2}{4} \right) + \frac12
 \Big(       n      \log n -       n       \Big)
\\
&=
\frac{n^2+n}{2}\log n - \frac{n^2+2n}{4}
\,.
}
$$
Thus
$$
G_n=e^{\log G_n}\rightarrow e^{\frac12}=\sqrt{e}
\,.
$$

Comment: How can you get this$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}logn-\frac{n(n+2)}{4}$

Comment: Integration by parts ($n\ge0$): $$\matrix{u=\log x&dv=x^n\\du=x^{-1}dx&v=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}}$$ $$\eqalign{\int x^n\,\log x\,dx&=\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du\\&=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}\log x-\int \frac1{n+1}x^n\,dx\\&=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}\log x-\frac1{(n+1)^2}x^{n+1}+c}$$

Answer (score 13):

In fact, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\prod_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\right]^{1/n^2} = \exp\left(1+2\int_{0}^{1}x\log x\; dx\right) = \sqrt{e}.$$

This follows from the identity

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\log \left[\prod_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\right] = 2\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j}{n}\log\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n} + \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\log n - \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}\log (n!),$$

together with the Stirling's formula.

In fact, I tried to write down the detailed derivation of this identity, but soon gave up since it's painstrikingly demanding to *type* $\LaTeX$ formulas in iPad2!

But you may begin with the identity

$$\log\binom{n}{k} = \log n! - \log k! - \log (n-k)!$$

and

$$ \log k! = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \log j,$$

and then you can change the order of summation.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: This is a great answer. I believe your second equation should read $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ instead of $\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)$. Of course, it doesn't affect your nice result. I deal with a related limit [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156296/26872). Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

G is geometric mean:

$$G=\sqrt[n]{C_n^0C_n^1C_n^2\cdots C_n^n}$$

Hence,

$$\ln G=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \ln C_k^n$$

Comment: Actually, I have already done this step, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I would just like to point out the obvious fact that there are $n+1$ binomial coefficients, not $n$, so the formulas need some adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but the sequence $(G_n)$ does not converge, neither to $\sqrt{\mathrm e}$ nor to any other finite limit.

For every fixed $k$, [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) yields ${2n\choose n+k}=2^{2n+o(n)}$. Keeping only the terms from $n-i$ to $n+i$ in $G_{2n}$, this yields, for every fixed nonnegative $i$ and every $n\geqslant i$,
$$
(G_{2n})^{2n+1}=\prod\limits_{k=-n}^n{2n\choose n+k}\geqslant\prod\limits_{k=-i}^i{2n\choose n+k}=2^{2n(2i+1)+o(n)},
$$
hence $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} G_n\geqslant2^{2i+1}$. Since this holds for every fixed $i$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} G_n=+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I made a big mistake.Please see the revision.

Comment: But what with the sequence $\small (G_n^{1 \over n}) $?

Comment: The divergence of $G_n$ can also be seen by noting $\binom{n}{k} \geq n} $ for $1\leq k \leq n-1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} G_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{C_n^0C_n^1C_n^2\cdots C_n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}}=\frac{n!}{G(n+2)^{2/n}},$$
where $G()$ is [Barnes G-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html). $\lim_{n\to \infty}G_n$ diverges as can be seen [here](http://tinyurl.com/cue7vyb).

Comment: Sorry I made a big mistake.Please see the revision.