# $\frac{1}{e}=$"Probability that every chocolate goes into a wrong spot".

Tags: probability, derangements

While watching a video by [Po Shen Loh](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5047E7efQAhXMvo8KHTFsAtYQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.cmu.edu%2F~ploh%2F&usg=AFQjCNEQa2Usv-HdkcJA-Evko7kEUn500w&sig2=h_oO1TWvnnz5DqWQ482Nvw&bvm=bv.141320020,d.c2I) I found something strange. In the video, he said that:

> Suppose I have a box of chocolates having $100$ chocolates, and I drop them all on the ground, and then I try to put them all back in. What is the probability that every chocolate went back in a wrong spot?

According to him, the probability is $\frac{1}{e}$. Now the question is that how can we get that? To me, It is as interesting as Buffon's Needle problem, that is why I am eager to know the method to reach at $\frac{1}{e}$. I shall be thankful if you guys can provide me idea about what is happening.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside we can also write the number of derangements you can form with $n$ elements as $!n$. Thus the total number of arrangements is $n!$ and the probability everything goes back in the wrong spot is $\frac{!n}{n!}$.

Comment: Other places where e pops up unexpectedly can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646042/what-are-some-surprising-appearances-of-e/1646085#1646085).

Comment: An exact formula for the number of derangements is  $\lfloor n! / e \rceil$, i.e. rounding to the nearest integer for $n \gt 0$.  You are then looking at the limit of  the probability $\dfrac{\lfloor n! / e \rceil}{n!}$, which is $\dfrac{1}{e}$

Comment: As a really really rough approximation (for exact you should do inclusion/exclusion), notice that for $n$ places, the probability that 1 chocolate goes to the wrong place is $1 - 1/n$.  Do it $n$ time is approximately $\left(1 - \frac 1n \right)^n$.  This isn't exactly since these are not independent events.  I've heard of this result being used by charlatans to amaze people that after shuffling a deck, not a single card went back to the correct place (works ~30% of the time).

Answer (score 10):

It is not exactly $\dfrac{1}{e}$. However the probability approaches $\dfrac{1}{e}$ as the number of chocolates tends to infinity.

What we are counting are the permutations over $\{1,..,n\}$ which do not a have a fixed point that is $\sigma(i)\not=i$ for every $i$. These are called derangements. The usual method for counting derangements is by using the inclusion-exclusion principle which gives that there are
$$n!\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
derangements over $\{1,..,n\}$. Since there are a total of $n!$ permutations it means the probability for random permutation to be a derangement is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
which tends to $\dfrac{1}{e}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ according to the formula
$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^i}{i!}$$

Comment: It approaches $1/{\rm e}$ really fast.  Like, 3 or 4 chocolates is enough to get a really accurate estimate.

Comment: An amusing application: Take 2 standard decks of 52 cards each. Shuffle one or both decks. Compare the $n$th card of one deck with the $n$th card of the other, for $n=1,...,52.$ Many people would be willing to bet that there is at least  a 50% chance there will be no match. When the actual chance is very close to $1/e$ which is about $0.368.$

Answer (score 7):

You are interested in the number of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the set of $100$ chocolates.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472), the number of Derangements of $n$ items is shown to be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{n!}{k!}
$$
which is the closest integer to $\frac{n!}e$ for $n\ge1$. Since there are $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ items, the probability of getting all objects into the wrong spot is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac1{k!}\approx\frac1e
$$
Note that this is approximate, it is not *exactly* $\frac1e$. By the [Alternating Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Proof_of_partial_sum_error_bound), the error is less than $\frac1{(n+1)!}$ which is very small, but not $0$. For $n=100$, the error is less than $\frac1{101!}\approx1.06\times10^{-160}$. In particular:

$$
\begin{array}{r}
\begin{array}{r}\scriptsize{p
=0.3678794411714423215955237701614608674458111310317678345078368016974614957448998}\\
\scriptsize{03357147274345919643746627325276843995208246975792790129008626653589494098783092\color{#C00}{299}}\end{array}\\[12pt]
\begin{array}{r}\scriptsize{\frac1e
=0.3678794411714423215955237701614608674458111310317678345078368016974614957448998}\\
\scriptsize{03357147274345919643746627325276843995208246975792790129008626653589494098783092\color{#C00}{194}}\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: However, for $n\ge 1$ the number of derangements is the integer nearest $\frac{n!}e$, so the approximation is very good even for rather small $n$: the relative error is a little under $2$% for $n=4$, a little under a third of a percent for $n=5$, and less than $0.05$% for $n=6$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I did mention that the number of derangements is the closest integer to $\frac{n!}e$. The approximation is very good, but it is still an approximation. That is, the probability is *not* $\frac1e$. I have added a bound on the error.

Comment: Oh, I agree that it’s important to note that it’s an approximation; I just thought that it was also a good idea to indicate how very good an approximation it is, since this explains why someone would use it without comment. (I did upvote, by the way.)